# SwiftUI Mac OS Как скрыть полосу TabView в верхней части экрана при Full Screen?

Tags: xcode, macos, mac, swiftui

Подскажите, как скрыть полосу TabView (квадратики переключения представлений) В full screen режиме экрана?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import SwiftUI
struct StartView: View {
    @ObservedObject var router = TabRouter()
    @ObservedObject var variables = Variables()
    
    var body: some View {
       
        TabView(selection: $router.screen ) {
            
            SettingsView(variables: variables)
                .tag(Screen.one)
                .environmentObject(router)
            
            ContentView(variables: variables)
                .tag(Screen.two)
                .environmentObject(router)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) - работает только пока не развернуть в full screen